# Gapless playback in flex video player

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4, flex4.5

Is there any way to customize flex video player as gapless video player with common time line.
Any idea.

Any web link or code sample would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what a gapless video player with a common timeline is.  Can you explain?  Which Flex Video Player are you using?  The MX one or the Spark one or something different?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have three videos, now i want to play these three videos one by one without having disturb when one video ends and next one starts, and common time line means, i want to treat three videos as a one video. Like if every three videos has 2 min length then i want to show full time in video player as 6 min. If i missed anything which can help you. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

It can be easily achieved using RTMP streaming server if available,

see this sample http://flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/rtmp.html#combining-streams

download the source code for this plugin and check how it's done using netstream,

here is the link: http://releases.flowplayer.org/flowplayer.rtmp/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.10-src.zip

Regards,